# Save current bing map view as an image

Tags: ajax, image, bing-maps

I am using Ajax Bing maps 7.0 and I'd like to generate an image from the current map view and then upload it somewhere. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, using a static map service. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on how complex your map is (in terms of what data you are showing on it) you are better off using the static map service to generate an image that matches your ajax map:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx